# Fastest way to compare hundreds of thousands of files, and create output results file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following:

-Values File, values.txt

-Directory Structure: ./dataset/label/author/files.txt

-Tens of thousands of files.txt's

-A file called targets.txt, which contains the location of every files.txt

Example targets.txt

```
./dataset/tallperson/Jabba/awesome.txt
./dataset/fatperson/Detox/toxic.txt
```

I have a file called values.txt, which contains hundreds of thousands of lines of values. These values are things like "aef", "; i", "jfk", etc. Random 3-Character lines.

I also have tens of thousands of files, each which also contain hundreds to thousands of lines. Each line also contains Random 3-Character lines.

The values.txt was created using the values of each files.txt. Therefore, there is no value in any file.txt file which isn't contained in values.txt. values.txt contains NO repeating values.

Example:

./dataset/weirdperson/Crooked/file1.txt

```
LOL
hel
lo 
how
are
you
on 
thi
s f
ine
day
```

./dataset/awesomeperson/Mild/file2.txt

```
I a
m v
ery
goo
d. 
Tha
nks
LOL
```

values.txt

```
are
you
on 
thi
s f
ine
day
goo
d. 
Tha
hel
lo 
how
I a
m v
ery
nks
LOL
```

The above is just example data. Each file will contain hundreds of lines. And values.txt will contain hundreds of thousands of lines.

My goal here is to make one file, where each line is a file. Each line will contain N values where each value is correspondant to the line in values.txt. And each value will be seperated by a comma. Each value is calculated simply by how many times each file contains the value of each line in values.txt.

The result should look something like this. With line 1 being file1.txt and line 2 being file2.txt.

Result.txt

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
```

Now. The last thing is, after getting this result I would like to add a label. The label is equivalent to the Nth parent directory from the file. For this example, lets say the 2nd parent directory. Therefore the label would be "tallperson" or "shortperson". As a result, the new Results.txt file would look like this.

Results.txt

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,weirdperson
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,awesomeperson
```

I would like a way to accomplish all of this, but I need it to be fast as I am working with a very large scale dataset.

This is my current code, but it's too slow. The bottleneck is line 2.

Script. Each file located at "./dataset/label/author/file.java"

```
1  while IFS= read file_name; do
2      cat values.txt | xargs -d '\n' -I {} grep -Fc -- "{}" "$file_name" | xargs printf "%d," >> Results.txt;
3      label=$(echo "$file_name" | cut -d '/' -f 3);
4      printf "$label\n" >> Results.txt;
5  done < targets.txt
```

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

To REPLICATE this problem. Do the following:

```
mkdir -p dataset/{label1,label2}
touch file1.txt; chmod 777 file1.txt
touch file2.txt; chmod 777 file2.txt
echo "Enter anything here" > file1.txt
echo "Enter something here too" > file2.txt
mv file1.txt ./dataset/label1
mv file2.txt ./dataset/label2
find ./dataset/ -type f -name "*.txt" | while IFS= read file_name; do cat $file_name | sed -e "s/.\{3\}/&\n/g" | sort -u > $modified-file_name; done
find ./dataset/ -type f -name "modified-*.txt" | xargs -d '\n' -I {} echo {} >> targets.txt
xargs cat < targets.txt | sort -u > values.txt
```

With the above UNCHANGED, you should get a values.txt with something similar to below. If there's any lines with less or more than 3 characters for some reason, please delete the line.

```
any
e
Ent
er 
eth
he
her
ing
ng 
re 
som
thi
too
```

You should get a targets.txt file

```
./dataset/label2/modified-file2.txt
./dataset/label1/modified-file1.txt
```

From here. The goal is to check every file in targets.txt, and count how many values the file has contained in values.txt. And to output the results with the label to Results.txt

The following script will work for this example, but I need it to be way faster for large scale operations.

```
while IFS= read file_name; do
  cat values.txt | xargs -d '\n' -I {} grep -Fc -- "{}" $file_name | xargs printf "%d," >> Results.txt;
  label=$(echo "$file_name" | cut -d '/' -f 3);
  printf "$label\n" >> Results.txt;
done < targets.txt
```

Here's another example

Example 2:

./dataset/weirdperson/Crooked/file1.txt

```
LOL
LOL
HAHA
```

./dataset/awesomeperson/Mild/file2.txt

```
LOL
LOL
LOL
```

values.txt

```
LOL
HAHA
```

Result.txt

```
2,1,weirdperson
3,0,awesomeperson
```

Comment: Your question is rather poorly structured and difficult to understand. All I can glean is that you have thousands and thousands of files, but as the description of the contents and sizes is so all over the place it is really hard to work out what you are trying to do. Maybe you could structure things better please?

Comment: It's very simple. I have many java files. I have 1 values file, and 1 targets file. I am simply counting how many times each value is found in each file from the targets file and outputting it to a frequency file with a label. However, I'd like to find the fastest solution. My provided code works but it's too slow.

Comment: An interesting problem, but still hard to picture. Is this Version 2 of your Q from June that we can see in your history, or really the same problem? The comment thread there offers good advice (which you seem to be mostly using). Good luck!

Comment: And think of it from our prespective. What is the smallest number of files we need to create to duplicate your problem. Yes the slowness won't show up w 10 files, but until we can see the flow of data through it stages, transformations, summations, it will be hard to help. The more effort you put into boiling this down to something we can cut/paste into our terminals, the more likely you are to get useful help. Good luck.

Comment: Bravo! Back in a while.

Comment: I hope I did a much better job modifying this. This problem is now able to be replicated. Thanks for the advice @Shellter

Comment: Maybe try dropping in [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), it's often much faster than grep

Comment: I'll try that. I'm ultimately going to be working with 65'728 files, and 289'936 values. As a result, I'm going to have 65'728 lines with 289'936 values per line. So I'm going to be writing at least 19056913408 results, plus that many commas. So 38113826816 Bytes which is going to be about 38 Gigabytes to write. This is why I'd like to have some speed.

Comment: To speed up significantly you're probably going to need to batch the searches. Doing an individual grep for each value for each file is very expensive. Maybe try greping for an individual value against all the files at once. Or use [grep's -f flag](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) to use targets.txt as the pattern source, which will search for all the patterns at once.

Comment: Yes, agree about `grep -f`. Also be aware there is an `-F` option, which means "fixed strings", but to be sure what this means for your project, I'd recommend doing some simple tests. From your sample data, do you want `ng` to match `ing` as well? If it must be "only match `ng` on a line", then you want `-F`, other wise not, but test, test, test on a project of this size ;-) . (I was writing up a comment or `grep -f srchList files ...`, but had a problem with my internet connection for a while). Glad you're making progress and getting more eyes on your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Oh yeah, and can the `-c` (count) option help you from `grep`?

Comment: Sorry, one other thing, your "modified" files references don't work when you copy paste. I'd recommend `.... sort -u > ${file_name}.mod` and then `find ./dataset/ -type f -name "*.mod" | xargs -I {} echo {} >> targets.txt` (my `find` doesn't support `-d`, and `\n` is the default value anyway).. Good luck.

Comment: Can any file.txt contain duplicated lines?

Comment: @Floegipoky that's a great idea. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @shellter I'm definitely going to try the -c option from grep later. I'll let you know my results tomorrow

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The values file contains no duplicate lines. The other files definitely can. In fact, if they do the frequency of that specific 3-gram goes up by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in Python, using its ordered dictionary datatype.

```
import os
from collections import OrderedDict

# read samples from values.txt into an Ordered Dict.
# each dict key is a line from the file
# (including the trailing newline, but that doesn't matter)
# each dict value is 0

with open('values.txt', 'r') as f:
  samplecount0=OrderedDict((sample, 0) for sample in f.readlines())

# get list of filenames from targets.txt

with open('targets.txt', 'r') as f:
  targets=[t.rstrip('\n') for t in f.readlines()]

# for each target,
# read its lines of samples
# increment the corresponding count in samplecount
# print out samplecount in a single line separated by commas
# each line also has the 2nd-to-last directory component of the target's pathname

for target in targets:
  with open(target, 'r') as f:
    # copy samplecount0 to samplecount so we don't have to read the values.txt file again
    samplecount=samplecount0.copy()
    # for each sample in the target file, increment the samplecount dict entry
    for tsample in f.readlines():
      samplecount[tsample] += 1
    output = ','.join(str(v) for v in samplecount.values())
    output += ',' + os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(target)))
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
$ python3  doit.py
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,weirdperson
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,awesomeperson
```

Comment: It's not a solution in bash like I wanted. However, it gets the job done very well.

Just a note, make sure there's UTF-8 characters only, or the python script fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<targets.txt xargs -n1 -P4 bash -c "
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[\$0];next} {if (\$0 in a) {printf \"1,\"} else {printf \"0,\"}}' \"\$1\" values.txt |
  sed $'s\x01$\x01'\"\$(<<<\"\$1\" cut -d/ -f3)\"'\n'$'\x01'
" --
```

The `-P4` let's you parallelize the jobs in `targets.txt`. The short awk script marges lines and prints 0 and 1 followed by a comma. Then `sed` is used to append the 3rd part of the folder path to the end of the line. The `sed` line looks strange, because I used unprintable character `$'\x01'` as the separator for `s` command.

Tested with:

```
mkdir -p ./dataset/weirdperson/Crooked
cat <<EOF >./dataset/weirdperson/Crooked/file1.txt
LOL
hel
lo 
how
are
you
on 
thi
s f
ine
day
EOF

mkdir -p ./dataset/awesomeperson/Mild/
cat <<EOF >./dataset/awesomeperson/Mild/file2.txt
I a
m v
ery
goo
d. 
Tha
nks
LOL
EOF

cat <<EOF >values.txt
are
you
on 
thi
s f
ine
day
goo
d. 
Tha
hel
lo 
how
I a
m v
ery
nks
LOL
EOF

cat <<EOF >targets.txt
./dataset/weirdperson/Crooked/file1.txt
./dataset/awesomeperson/Mild/file2.txt
EOF

measure_start() {
  declare -g ttic_start
  echo "==> Test $* <=="
  ttic_start=$(date +%s.%N)
}
measure_end() {
  local end
  end=$(date +%s.%N) 
  local start   
  start="$ttic_start"
  ttic_runtime=$(python -c "print(${end} - ${start})")
  echo "Runtime: $ttic_runtime"
  echo
}

measure_start original
while IFS= read file_name; do
  cat values.txt | xargs -d '\n' -I {} grep -Fc -- "{}" $file_name | xargs printf "%d,"
  label=$(echo "$file_name" | cut -d '/' -f 3);
  printf "$label\n"
done < targets.txt
measure_end

measure_start first try with bash
nl -w1 values.txt | sort -k2.2 > values_sorted.txt
< targets.txt xargs -n1 -P0 bash -c "
  sort -t$'\t' \"\$1\" |
  join -t$'\t' -12 -21 -eEMPTY -a1 -o1.1,2.1 values_sorted.txt - |
  sort -s -n -k1.1 |
  sed 's/.*\tEMPTY/0/;t;s/.*/1/' |
  tr '\n' ',' |
  sed $'s\x01$\x01'\"\$(<<<\"\$1\" cut -d/ -f3)\"'\n'$'\x01'
" --
measure_end

measure_start second try with awk
<targets.txt xargs -n1 -P0 bash -c "
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[\$0];next} {if (\$0 in a) {printf \"1,\"} else {printf \"0,\"}}' \"\$1\" values.txt |
  sed $'s\x01$\x01'\"\$(<<<\"\$1\" cut -d/ -f3)\"'\n'$'\x01'
" --
measure_end
```

Outputs:

```
==> Test original <==
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,weirdperson
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,awesomeperson
Runtime: 0.133769512177

==> Test first try with bash <==
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,awesomeperson
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,weirdperson
Runtime: 0.0322473049164

==> Test second try with awk <==
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,awesomeperson
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,weirdperson
Runtime: 0.0180222988129
```

Comment: Oh my god I have soo much to learn. Thanks for this input, I will try it out tomorrow and let you know my results. I appreciate this!

Comment: I see what's going on with your script. I don't know AWK well enough to fix it I don't think, however I do see that "{if (\$0 in a) {printf \"1,\"} else {printf \"0,\"}}". 

Instead of printing 1's and 0's, I need it to print how many occurences there are. I completely forgot to specify that more clearly, sorry.

Comment: I just added an example 2 to further clarify

Comment: Is there a way to do this so it prints the number of occurrences instead of "1" if contains else "0"?

Comment: Probably there is. I would go with just preprocessing the input files with `sort | uniq -c`, then search for the words and output the count of the matching the word instead of 1. I don't like the `{a[\$0];next}` part - if you file has milions of lines, `awk` will fill up memory real quick. The bash metchod would be more flexible, changing first sort to `sort "$1" | uniq -c | join ... -22 .. -a0 -o 1.1,2.1`. Probably one could remove the `sed`. I am not good in `awk`, but I would read the `sort input.txt | uniq -c` into a 2d array, and just output the count if the matching word is found.